# Why can't I have conditions like this in for loop? (C++)

Tags: c++

Is this legal?

```
int sum {0};
for (int i=1; (i % 2 != 0) and (i <= 15); i++)
    sum += i;
```

Comment: And what is illegal about this?

Comment: Have you tried compiling, and running it?

Comment: @StaceyGirl I think that's the question :)

Comment: "_Why can't I have conditions like this in for loop?_" -Who says you can't?

Comment: I had a quiz and when I submitted this, the program always return result as 1

Comment: @DatLe Well, that is the correct result for this loop. Try stepping through it with a debugger. It's not clear what other value you expected.

Comment: It returns 1 because the condition `i % 2 != 0` fails when `i == 2` and the loop exits with `sum = 1`

Comment: Did you mean to do `for (int i=1; (i <= 15); i+=2)`?

Comment: Thanks Varun, I got it now. It's painful to be a noob :((

Comment: We are all learners here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant to add all odd numbers up to 15, this is what you should have instead.

```cpp
int sum {0};
for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i += 2)
    sum += i;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Thank you

Comment: Could you mark the answer as accepted?